# Conditional WHERE based on SQL Server parameter value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am modifying an existing stored procedure in SQL server and trying to come up with a query that should take a conditional `WHERE` depending on whether one of the input parameters is `null` or has value.

The stored procedure takes three input parameters

```
@FromDate
@ToDate
@PersonnelNo
```

`@FromDate` and `@ToDate` will always have value and will be part of the `WHERE` condition but `@PersonnelNo` can be null or can hold value.

When `@PersonnelNo` is null I want all users for the given `@FromDate` and to `@ToDate` date but when the parameter `@PersonnelNo` has a value then I want the stored procedure to return data for that user only.

I’ve tried the below two approaches but it only works (gives one user record correctly) when I input value for `@PersonnelNo`. It doesn’t return any record if I input `@PersonnelNo` as `null`, rather I want all users.

Any idea where I’m going wrong or is that possible at all with the current approach I am taking?

```
SELECT  FirstName,
        LastName,
        PersonnelNum,
        RecCreatedOn
FROM    [test].Person
WHERE   RecCreatedOn BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
        AND (
         (ISNULL(@PersonnelNo, 0) != 0 AND PersonnelNum = @PersonnelNo)
        )
```

and a slightly different WHERE clause

```
WHERE   RecCreatedOn BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
        AND ((@PersonnelNo IS NOT NULL) AND PersonnelNum = @PersonnelNo)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works by saying if @PersonnelNo is null the replace it with PeronnelNum.  PersonnelNum will always equal PersonnelNum, so if @PersonnelNo is null this condition will always be true.

```
SELECT  FirstName,
        LastName,
        PersonnelNum,
        RecCreatedOn
FROM    [test].Person
WHERE   RecCreatedOn BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
AND     (@PersonnelNo is null or PersonnelNum = @PersonnelNo)
```

Explanation of your previous attempts:

```
ISNULL(@PersonnelNo, 0) != 0 AND PersonnelNum = @PersonnelNo
```

If @PersonnelNo is null this becomes:

- `0 != 0 and PersonnelNum = 0`.
- This becomes `false and false`
- which becomes `false`
- so no rows will be returned

If @PersonnelNo is (e.g.) 1 this becomes:

- `1 != 0 and PersonnelNum = 1`.
- This becomes `true and true (for the row where PersonnelNum is 1)`
- which becomes `true`
- so you will see the row for person 1.

  (@PersonnelNo IS NOT NULL) AND PersonnelNum = @PersonnelNo

If @PersonnelNo is null this becomes:

- `(null is not null) and PersonnelNum = null`.
- This becomes `false and false`
- which becomes `false`
- so no rows will be returned

If @PersonnelNo is (e.g.) 1 this becomes:

- `1 is not null and PersonnelNum = 1`.
- This becomes `true and true (for the row where PersonnelNum is 1)`
- which becomes `true`
- so you will see the row for person 1.

Methods which do work:

- `PersonnelNum = coalesce(@PersonnelNo,PersonnelNum)`
- `(@PersonnelNo is null or PersonnelNum = @PersonnelNo)`

There's a minor difference between the methods above though.  If `PersonnelNum` is nullable you may get different results; i.e. the `coalesce` method wouldn't include rows with a null value in this column whilst the second method will.

Comment: Great.. what if there is an exiting record with a `null` personnelNo and passing null for `@PersonnelNo`, will it return the user with null personnelNo?

Comment: That won't be an issue since (confusingly) null doesn't equal null (and also it doesn't not equal null).  To explain, if you ask someone their age and they reply "I don't know" you can't say they're the same age as another person who says "I don't know", even though they gave the same answer to the question.

Comment: Here's some examples to better illustrate this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8.  If you're interested there's also a great article on many valued logic here, which is far more confusing than SQL's nulls: http://aeon.co/magazine/world-views/logic-of-buddhist-philosophy/

Comment: No worries.  FYI: better illustration of null comparisons here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8ee1f/3

Comment: Actually just had a rethink / amended my answer based on your null question.  Whilst you won't have the issue of only `null` `personnelNum`s being returned, you will have the issue that those don't get returned when you're expecting everything.  See revised query & amended explanation (last sentence) in answer above.

Comment: Good..that explains it. I'll try it out and compare the results.